# Maven dependencies are not copied to WEB-INF/lib in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, m2e

I have a maven web project in Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite to be precise), and for some reason my maven dependencies do not end up in WEB-INF/lib, so I get all sorts of runtime errors. This was working last week, and I'm not sure what action caused it to stop working. Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly shows Maven Dependencies deploying to WEB-INF/lib, and I've tried to do Maven -> Update Project, restart the IDE, clean/install, etc. Here is my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
    <artifactId>kdweb</artifactId>
    <name>kdweb</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>acommons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>aggregation-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn</artifactId>
            <version>3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks.thirdparty</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6_g</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>abizcommons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ks</groupId>
            <artifactId>apods-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/kdweb</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</id>
            <name>xxxxxxxxxxxx-releases</name>
            <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>xxxxxxxxxx</id>
            <name>xxxxxxxxxx-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you creating the war? What dependencies are missing? What errors do you get?

Comment: m2e creates the war when I do Run As -> Maven Install.  ALL of the dependencies are missing. The errors are classpath errors resulting from the dependencies not being on the classpath.

Comment: Have you tried running `mvn package` from the command line? I never trust IDE plugins that just automate command-line build tools. Drop down to the low-level to test it yourself.

Comment: Tried it from the command line, and it had the same result.

Comment: Did you open up the war file and verify that the jars are missing from WEB-INF/lib? Have you tried running `mvn dependency:tree` to verify your dependencies are being interpreted ok by Maven? What app server are you deploying to? Exactly which class is not found?

Comment: I suppose I wasn't clear enough when describing the issue.  It's not that a few dependencies are missing from WEB-INF/lib, the problem is that WEB-INF/lib doesn't even exist.  None of the dependencies are there.  I'm deploying to Tomcat.

Comment: is that the full POM posted in your question? Try to invoke `mvn -X package` and see if any interesting output shows when the maven-war-plugin executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you metioned that your build was working, try switching to a new workspace and recreate your project. See if the problem is solved.

Comment: This eventually fixed it, as it does with way too many Eclipse issues.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). It solved all my dependency installation trouble.